# Chasam Sofer's Commentary on The Month of Av

Tags: simchah-joy-happiness

There's a famous gemara that states:  “Mishenichnas Av mema’atim b’simchah,” “When Av enters, we decrease our joy,” (Taanis 26b)

I heard that the Chasam Sofer has an explanation of what it means to "decrease our joy." Does anyone know where this is?

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/3305